# Select records that have at least one link to other tables

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-12, query-performance

I want to select all users that have either a post, a photo or a video. I came up with the following query.

```sql
select
  users.username
from
  users
where
  exists (select * from posts where users.id = posts.user_id)
  or exists (select * from photos where users.id = photos.user_id)
  or exists (select * from videos where users.id = videos.user_id)
```

Everything works perfectly, but I also need to determine if a user has a particular record on each table, so I'm using:

```sql
select
  users.username,
  EXISTS (select * from posts where users.id = posts.user_id) as has_post,
  EXISTS (select * from photos where users.id = photos.user_id) as has_photo,
  EXISTS (select * from videos where users.id = videos.user_id) as has_video
from
  users
where
  exists (select * from posts where users.id = posts.user_id)
  or exists (select * from photos where users.id = photos.user_id)
  or exists (select * from videos where users.id = videos.user_id)
```

The query above works but it's slow, how can I optimize it? I'm also open to other alternatives.

All `id` columns are primary keys and all `user_id` columns are foreign keys, `users.username` is a `unique` column.

---

**Update**

The execution plans below are executed in a development environment with much less data but same database schema (I can feel the slowness in production too, but I don't have access)

```
Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..79803.74 rows=3883 width=18) (actual time=0.799..7.069 rows=297 loops=1)
  Filter: ((alternatives: SubPlan 1 or hashed SubPlan 2) OR (alternatives: SubPlan 3 or hashed SubPlan 4) OR (alternatives: SubPlan 5 or hashed SubPlan 6))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 4141
  Buffers: shared hit=146
  SubPlan 1
    ->  Seq Scan on posts  (cost=0.00..17.11 rows=2 width=0) (never executed)
          Filter: (users.id = user_id)
  SubPlan 2
    ->  Seq Scan on posts posts_1  (cost=0.00..16.29 rows=329 width=4) (actual time=0.007..0.120 rows=329 loops=1)
          Buffers: shared hit=13
  SubPlan 3
    ->  Seq Scan on photos  (cost=0.00..5.49 rows=1 width=0) (never executed)
          Filter: (users.id = user_id)
  SubPlan 4
    ->  Seq Scan on photos photos_1  (cost=0.00..5.19 rows=119 width=4) (actual time=0.008..0.037 rows=119 loops=1)
          Buffers: shared hit=4
  SubPlan 5
    ->  Seq Scan on videos  (cost=0.00..7.80 rows=2 width=0) (never executed)
          Filter: (users.id = user_id)
  SubPlan 6
    ->  Seq Scan on videos videos_1  (cost=0.00..7.04 rows=304 width=4) (actual time=0.009..0.066 rows=304 loops=1)
          Buffers: shared hit=4
Planning Time: 1.229 ms
Execution Time: 7.296 ms
```

The second query

```
Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..149479.32 rows=3883 width=21) (actual time=354.809..368.271 rows=297 loops=1)
  Filter: ((alternatives: SubPlan 7 or hashed SubPlan 8) OR (alternatives: SubPlan 9 or hashed SubPlan 10) OR (alternatives: SubPlan 11 or hashed SubPlan 12))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 4141
  Buffers: shared hit=167
  SubPlan 1
    ->  Seq Scan on posts  (cost=0.00..17.11 rows=2 width=0) (never executed)
          Filter: (users.id = user_id)
  SubPlan 2
    ->  Seq Scan on posts posts_1  (cost=0.00..16.29 rows=329 width=4) (actual time=16.649..16.776 rows=329 loops=1)
          Buffers: shared hit=13
  SubPlan 3
    ->  Seq Scan on photos  (cost=0.00..5.49 rows=1 width=0) (never executed)
          Filter: (users.id = user_id)
  SubPlan 4
    ->  Seq Scan on photos photos_1  (cost=0.00..5.19 rows=119 width=4) (actual time=12.576..12.634 rows=119 loops=1)
          Buffers: shared hit=4
  SubPlan 5
    ->  Seq Scan on videos  (cost=0.00..7.80 rows=2 width=0) (never executed)
          Filter: (users.id = user_id)
  SubPlan 6
    ->  Seq Scan on videos videos_1  (cost=0.00..7.04 rows=304 width=4) (actual time=12.815..13.606 rows=304 loops=1)
          Buffers: shared hit=4
  SubPlan 7
    ->  Seq Scan on posts posts_2  (cost=0.00..17.11 rows=2 width=0) (never executed)
          Filter: (users.id = user_id)
  SubPlan 8
    ->  Seq Scan on posts posts_3  (cost=0.00..16.29 rows=329 width=4) (actual time=15.300..15.822 rows=329 loops=1)
          Buffers: shared hit=13
  SubPlan 9
    ->  Seq Scan on photos photos_2  (cost=0.00..5.49 rows=1 width=0) (never executed)
          Filter: (users.id = user_id)
  SubPlan 10
    ->  Seq Scan on photos photos_3  (cost=0.00..5.19 rows=119 width=4) (actual time=14.130..14.184 rows=119 loops=1)
          Buffers: shared hit=4
  SubPlan 11
    ->  Seq Scan on videos videos_2  (cost=0.00..7.80 rows=2 width=0) (never executed)
          Filter: (users.id = user_id)
  SubPlan 12
    ->  Seq Scan on videos videos_3  (cost=0.00..7.04 rows=304 width=4) (actual time=18.024..18.103 rows=304 loops=1)
          Buffers: shared hit=4
Planning Time: 1.567 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 106
  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 49.689 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 15.154 ms, Emission 312.171 ms, Total 377.014 ms
Execution Time: 471.659 ms
```

Comment: Test `SELECT users.username, EXISTS (...) as has_post, ... FROM users GROUP BY users.username HAVING has_post+has_photo+has_video > 0`.

Comment: @Akina I can't use aliases in having, I've even removed the `having` part and the `group by` alone doesn't work: `subquery uses ungrouped column "users.id" from outer query`. I'm not even sure why do I need to group, I don't have duplicate records.

Comment: Add `users.id` into grouping expression, what a problem&

Comment: I've added `users.id` and duplicated all `EXISTS (...)` in `having` (because postgresql doesn't allow aliases), the query works but it's as much slow as my second query.

Comment: Are you saying the 2nd query is slow but the first one is not?  Please edit to include an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for each one, preferably with track_io_timing turned on.

Comment: Please consider reading about [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: @jjanes question updated. I can totally change the query and I may add indexes if it's necessary. I also have reindexed the development database just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2nd query is activating [JIT (Just-In-Time compilation)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/jit.html), which is very counterproductive for you.  312 out of 472 ms is spent in the JIT. If you don't know that you benefit from JIT for other plans, then I would just turn JIT off globally.  I think it was a mistake that they turned JIT on by default in version 12, as it seems to hurt at least as many cases as it helps.  If you don't want to turn it off globally, then you could play with some of the other JIT parameters.

Also, I wouldn't think the plans you posted match your posted queries.  Did you simplify your queries before posting?

Comment: Disabling JIT significantly improved the performance, thanks! If it was not enabled before, I don't mind disabling it now, I have to read to pros/cons of JIT to decide, we are in the middle of upgrading to version 12. Nice catch, I did use another database for testing this particular issue. Last question, Can I rewrite my query with `join`? I've tried but no luck, I'm just wondering if it's possible.

Comment: You could probably write it as a join, but you would have have to do lateral joins with LIMIT 1, or else you would start getting duplicates returned.  So I wouldn't bother trying.  Also, I think it would be less clear.

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
select u.username
     , count(x.user_id) as has_post
     , count(y.user_id) as has_photo
     , count(z.user_id) as has_video
from users u
left join lateral ( 
    select p.user_id 
    from posts p
    where u.id = p.user_id
    limit 1
) as x
left join lateral ( 
    select p.user_id 
    from photos p
    where u.id = p.user_id
    limit 1
) as y
left join lateral ( 
    select v.user_id 
    from videos v
    where u.id = v.user_id
    limit 1
) as z
group by u.username;
```